# Definition standard algebraic structures with commutative diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, set-theory

I'm working on a document where I explain standard set theory, boolean logic, and algebraic structures as an intro to higher mathematics (think math AND CS undergrads; so not always the most "algebra-savvy/proof-hungry" public). The goal of this text is to prepare the students' minds for readings more technical than mine: I mostly concentrate on teaching vocabulary, relations between concepts, and useful intuitions/mental models.

I'd like to add a section at the end where I demystify category theory (though my experience with it at this point comes mostly from functional programming). I know most (all?) algebraic formulae can be expressed in the form of a commutative diagram, and for example, I explain the notion of a commutative diagram itself by showing how linearity can be defined both with and without them, ie:

$$\forall (x,y) \in E^2, f(x +_E y) = f(x) +_F f(y) \\
\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{K}, \forall x \in E, f(\lambda \cdot_E x) = \lambda \cdot_F f(x)$$

and

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{tikzcd}
  E \times E   \arrow[r, "{(f,f)}"] \arrow[d, "+_E"]
    & F \times F \arrow[d, "+_F"] \\
    E       \arrow[r, "f"]
      & F
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
  K \times E   \arrow[r, "{(id_{\mathbb{K}},f)}"] \arrow[d, "*_E"]
    & K \times F \arrow[d, "*_F"] \\
    E       \arrow[r, "f"]
      & F
\end{tikzcd}
```

(sorry, I'm not sure how to use this package within math stackexchange; I don't this package very well either)

My question is: what would be the "right" way of describing the following properties as commutative diagrams ?

- stability/closure (maybe that's a given in category theory ?)
- associativity
- identity/existence of a neutral element
- invertibility/existence of a symmetric involution
- commutativity
- distributivity
- anything else which I might be forgetting which you think would be relevant; maybe the definitions of de Morgan's laws, of relations that are actually functions in Rel, etc ?

Maybe my confusion stems from not really knowing how to present $\forall$ and $\exists$ (and sequences of these) as constructs of commutative diagrams. So any advice or explanations on the matter is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: Also, if you know some good entry level works in CT that go over the distinctions between the various categories of sets (Set, Rel, and Inj) that I could use as inspiration, I'm interested.

Comment: Alot of this is standard.   Look up, for example, the definition of group object in a category.

Comment: Here's a link with diagrams:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Gives me the diagonal map to explain as well, which is interesting to add.